# Day from date EXTRACT(DAY,s.date) is not working jpa and eclipseLink

Tags: java, date, jpa, eclipselink, named-query

I have JPA2 and EclipseLink 2.7.3 i am unsing folloing eclipseLink version documentation the EXTRACT FUNCTION but it is not working

https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.7/jpa/extensions/jpql.htm#CHDJGBFJ

```
@NamedQuery(name = User.FIND_USER_CWC_ERROR_TODAY,
query = "select u from User u,Score s where u.id =s.userId and s.status=com.model.Status.ERROR and s.scoreType = com.model.ScoreType.CREDIT and EXTRACT(DAY,s.lastExecutionDate) = EXTRACT(DAY,CURRENT_DATE) ")
```

The identification variable 'EXTRACT' is not defined in the FROM clause.

I really do not understand the error

Answer (score 0):

I really don't know why it is not working but i found a workaround

```
select u from User u,Score s where u.id =s.userId and s.status=com.model.Status.ERROR 
and s.scoreType = com.model.ScoreType.CREDIT and FUNC('DAY',s.lastExecutionDate) = 
FUNC('DAY',CURRENT_DATE)
```

It is working like that